# react js ошбика в консоле (warning) при использовании компонента autocomplete mui

Tags: reactjs, mui

есть такой autocomplete mui

```
<Autocomplete
  id="instruments"
  options={allInstruments}
  value={instrument}
  onChange={(event, newValue) => handleInstruments(newValue)}
  defaultValue={allInstruments[0]}
  size="small"
  sx={{ mt: 0.2, flexGrow: 2 }}
  getOptionLabel={tool => tool.title}
  renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} label="Инструменты" />}
/>
```

когда включаю его в рендер в консоле появляется ошибка
The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.
None of the options match with `{"id":0,"name":"Все авторы"}`.
You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality test.
подскажите как это пофиксить?